# c# DataContractSerializer serializing List

Tags: c#, list, datacontractserializer

Is there chance if you remove item from list which is decorated with DataMember attribute but you find that item inside output (XML)?

Thanks.

Comment: If you already remove that item and then serialize it, that item is gone and not exists at your output.

Comment: Interestingly it is inside of output of serialization however deserialization works correctly.

Comment: @Tim, can you provide a repro example for that case? Would be a huge bug if that was true...

Comment: Sorry @Abbondanza for late response. Unfortunately, no. Because there are many classes in a project. It seems it is not a bug, it looks like even I am removing it from list, because of having references in other Lists, I missed something. Thanks for your attention.